# How to load 3D models in OpenGL C++?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to load 3D models. How do I to read the data in the model file?

For an example, this is the data:

```
VERTICES
80 21 32
32 34 17
14 93 56
33 54 87
MODEL_SCALE 5
```

I know the data in 3D models is not like this, but how will I read the 'vertex data' and the 'model scale amount'?

Comment: The best piece of advice is to get [OpenCTM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCTM), that does mesh loading, etc. for you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OpenGL doesn't do this for you. You should write your own parser, store the readed datas into your defined data structures and use OpenGL primitives to render them.

Here's a nice [tutorial](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/model_loading/16004/).

Comment: Yes but how will I read the data? What I want to do is read the data of the file and draw vertices on them.

Comment: It looks like milkshape is a binary format, which I'm not sure is applicable for OP as it looks like he's showing an example of a text format.

Comment: Hmm... seems quite helpful. But there is a way reading words with string.h and other stuff like that, right? I'll try to use that too. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @CppOgl: FILE *filp = fopen(filename, "r"); fread(...), etc. Or in C++ using ifstream. This not an OpenGL question then, but a generic "how do I read a file" question.

Comment: @user786653 : yes you are right. But like datenwolf pointed out, this is not an opengl question. The linked tutorial illustrate some basic operation and datastrutctures that one usually use while loading a model to be rendered with openGL primitives.

Comment: Actually, NeHe's tutorials are not always useful which is why I'm a bit stuck on loading external models. Otherwise, Nehe's site comes on the first page when searched in google.

Comment: @CppOgl: When I was studying openGL nehe's tutorial have been very useful to me. But I think what you have problem with seems not related to opengl, but to file parsing.

Comment: Could be. I have seen many model loading tutorials but most of them are never helpful

Comment: @0verbose: It wasn't meant as a criticism of your post, the OP is extremely vague, so I was just pointing out that perhaps the OP was looking for something more like [this](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/3DS_ASCII_Loader.shtml). (Not tested, found by googling "asc opengl" where asc was just the first text 3d model format I could think of).

Comment: @user786653 : don't worry. no problem. even the criticism are always well accepted. I think that everyone of us should be here to improve his knowledge.